# Site search not working as expected for explicit strings

Tags: support

While attempting to respond to a particular question on the main site, potentially involving jQuery no-conflict, I attempted to search the site for previous questions/answers in included explicitly `jQuery +"no-conflict"` (and a second attempt at just `"no-conflict"`). In both cases, [the search results returned hits for `"conflict"` rather than for `"no-conflict"`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22no-conflict%22).

Is there something wrong with the search function, or do I just need more coffee?

Comment: It seems that "no" is disregarded completely in index http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=no&submit=search

Comment: @Rarst so how do we fix that?

Comment: Try [noconflict](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=noconflict).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From brief checking in at mod room and global meta:

- [SO sites don't search for common words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/so-sites-dont-search-for-common-words)
- [Need to be able to search for "stop words" on English.SE because they are often the most salient search term](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/need-to-be-able-to-search-for-stop-words-on-english-se-because-they-are-often)

Basically:

1. yes it works like that
2. use Google instead

**[update]**

It seems that in future current search backend is getting scrapped and replaced with better solution, that will allow precise matching: [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)

Comment: Sure enough, [Google site search returns meaningful results](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+%2B+%22no-conflict%22&sitesearch=wordpress.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions). I understand the need for search filtering, but a filter that strips words from explicit search strings (such as `jquery +"no-conflict"`) are... well, I would say "*asinine*", but I'll be more gracious, and leave it at "*short-sighted*".

Comment: @Chip Bennett I don't disagree, but we have what we have :) sadly search at SE has bit of a history of being non-priority... If there wasn't Google I'd guess it would be different story, but there just isn't enough pressure as it is.

Comment: *"We have what we have"* - yes, but it creates a compounded problem. We already have enough trouble dealing with duplicate questions. Consider the question at hand: we've dealt with the jQuery no-conflict question *ad nauseum*, and yet new users **can't actually search the site** to find those questions. (And no: they're not going to click a blank search, then submit a new search query from the Google field in the Search Tips page. That's just not practical, nor is it reasonable to expect new users to jump through such hoops.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a single case, where "more coffee" isn't the right suggestion. No matter if that will be the solution, but **yes, more coffee**.

[image]